# Home-made encryptor sometimes gets letters wrong

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a homemade text encryptor and it works fine - apart from the fact that sometimes it decrypts the message incorrectly. Please see the code example (sorry it's really messy, I'm just starting with HTML/JS):

*To see it make a mistake, type 'hi there' as the message and 'moo123' as the key. Don't ask why, I was just trying random words when I found the issue. Then copy the encrypted message into the text input with the same key then press decrypt. It says 'ho there' instead.*

Can anybody tell me why this is happening and also how to fix it? Thank you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Encryptor</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: monospace;
            }
            input {
                font-family: monospace;
                width: 400px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Encryptor</h1>
        <p>Enter the text to encrypt:</p>
        <input type="text" id="text">
        <p>Enter the encrytion key:</p>
        <input type="text" id="key"><br><br>
        <button onclick="encrypt()">Encrypt</button>
        <button onclick="decrypt()">Decrypt</button><br><br>
        <p id="output"></p>
        <p id="debug"></p>
        
        <script>
            function encrypt() {
                //console.log("----------------");
                var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
                var key = document.getElementById("key").value;
                var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&_={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&-={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&-={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ ";
                //var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                var output = "";
                var keyNum = 0;
                var char = "";
                var keychar = "";
                var finalchar = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    char = chars.search((text.substring(i, i+1)))+87;
                    //console.log("char "+char);
                    //keychar = chars.search(key.substring(keyNum, KeyNum+1));
                    //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = key.substring(keyNum, keyNum+1);
                    keychar = (chars.search(key.substring(keyNum, keyNum+1)));
                    //console.log("keychar "+keychar);
                    //console.log("char - keychar "+parseFloat(char)-parseFloat(keychar));
                    finalchar = chars[parseFloat(char)-parseFloat(keychar)];
                    
                    output = output + finalchar;
                    if (keyNum >= key.length-1) {
                        keyNum = 0;
                    } else {
                        keyNum++;
                    }
                    
                }
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
            }
            
            function decrypt() {
                //console.log("----------------");
                var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
                var key = document.getElementById("key").value;
                var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&_={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&_={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&_={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ ";
                //var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                var output = "";
                var keyNum = 0;
                var char = "";
                var keychar = "";
                var finalchar = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    char = chars.search((text.substring(i, i+1)));
                    //console.log("char "+char);
                    //keychar = chars.search(key.substring(keyNum, KeyNum+1));
                    //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = key.substring(keyNum, keyNum+1);
                    keychar = (chars.search(key.substring(keyNum, keyNum+1)))+87;
                    //console.log("keychar "+keychar);
                    //console.log("char - keychar "+parseFloat(char)-parseFloat(keychar));
                    finalchar = chars[parseFloat(char)+parseFloat(keychar)];
                    
                    output = output + finalchar;
                    if (keyNum >= key.length-1) {
                        keyNum = 0;
                    } else {
                        keyNum++;
                    }
                    
                }
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at `String.prototype.charCodeAt(position)`, using existing char table can make the code much easier to read and maintain

Comment: Haven't quite figured it out but I have narrowed it down to encrypting any string with space char in it has a problem regardless of key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `string.prototype.search` which [assumes a regular expression as input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).  Some of the characters in your string will not work properly because of this.  For example, if you encrypt `hi` it will return `/.` but `.` is "any character" so it will return `0` as the match.  Use `indexOf` instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Encryptor</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: monospace;
            }
            input {
                font-family: monospace;
                width: 400px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Encryptor</h1>
        <p>Enter the text to encrypt:</p>
        <input type="text" id="text">
        <p>Enter the encrytion key:</p>
        <input type="text" id="key"><br><br>
        <button onclick="encrypt()">Encrypt</button>
        <button onclick="decrypt()">Decrypt</button><br><br>
        <p id="output"></p>
        <p id="debug"></p>
        
        <script>
            function encrypt() {
                //console.log("----------------");
                var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
                var key = document.getElementById("key").value;
                var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&_={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&_={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&_={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ ";
                //var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                var output = "";
                var keyNum = 0;
                var char = "";
                var keychar = "";
                var finalchar = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    char = chars.indexOf((text.substring(i, i+1)))+87;
                    //console.log("char "+char);
                    //keychar = chars.search(key.substring(keyNum, KeyNum+1));
                    //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = key.substring(keyNum, keyNum+1);
                    keychar = (chars.indexOf(key.substring(keyNum, keyNum+1)));
                    //console.log("keychar "+keychar);
                    //console.log("char - keychar "+parseFloat(char)-parseFloat(keychar));
                    finalchar = chars[parseFloat(char)-parseFloat(keychar)];
                    
                    output = output + finalchar;
                    if (keyNum >= key.length-1) {
                        keyNum = 0;
                    } else {
                        keyNum++;
                    }
                    
                }
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
            }
            
            function decrypt() {
                //console.log("----------------");
                var text = document.getElementById("text").value;
                var key = document.getElementById("key").value;
                var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&_={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&_={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!£$%^&_={}:;@'~#<,>./|`¬ ";
                //var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                var output = "";
                var keyNum = 0;
                var char = "";
                var keychar = "";
                var finalchar = "";
                for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                    char = chars.indexOf((text.substring(i, i+1)));
                    //console.log("char "+char);
                    //keychar = chars.search(key.substring(keyNum, KeyNum+1));
                    //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = key.substring(keyNum, keyNum+1);
                    keychar = (chars.indexOf(key.substring(keyNum, keyNum+1)))+87;
                    //console.log("keychar "+keychar);
                    //console.log("char - keychar "+parseFloat(char)-parseFloat(keychar));
                    finalchar = chars[parseFloat(char)+parseFloat(keychar)];
                    
                    output = output + finalchar;
                    if (keyNum >= key.length-1) {
                        keyNum = 0;
                    } else {
                        keyNum++;
                    }
                    
                }
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, note that your two char strings aren't actually identical if you closely compare them.  That might also be an issue, but I'm not sure if it was intentional (I assume not)? *Now corrected*

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing this! Have you corrected my mistake with the char strings? I'm not expecting you to, I just want to check before I go searching!

Comment: I have not.  the 2nd and 3rd instance of `-` or `_` are different in the two.